# Query a database with a string that contains "/"

Tags: android, sqlite

I store a date in my database format "MM/dd/yyyy" and I want to do a query by a specific date but when I make the query the cursor returns nothing.

Is it because of the "/" that is in the string or something else? And yes I know the date is stored properly in the database

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),Games.GAMES_URI,new String[] {Games.GAMES_ID},Games.GAMES_DATE + "="+dt,
                null,null);
}
```

converting the date

```
public convertDate(Calendar date){
        mDate = date;           
        Date d = new Date(date.getTimeInMillis());
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dt = df.format(d);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code showing your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are trying to do will look like:

```
... WHERE games_date=08/11/2012
```

where it needs to be:

```
... WHERE games_date="08/11/2012"
```

(assuming that `games_date` is the name of the column -- replace as needed)

Try `Games.GAMES_DATE + "=?"` for your fourth `CursorLoader` constructor parameter, and `{dt}` for your fifth `CursorLoader` constructor parameter, and Android/SQLite will automatically add your quotation marks for you where needed, assuming that your `ContentProvider` is backed by SQLite.

Also, you might consider storing your date in some other format. If you want it to be a string, `yyyy-MM-dd` (or `yyyy/MM/dd`) is a better choice, as it will sort correctly in chronological order. If you do not need it to be a string, just storing `getTimeInMillis()` in an `INTEGER` column will make it easier to convert to and from `Date` objects without messing with string conversions.

Comment: I made that change but it still didnt return anything, I does not need to be a string I used a string because since I use `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` to get the date, then when I query I would have to have not only the date but then time to match the mills stored from `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @tyczj: Sorry, but I do not know what to tell you. Either `dt` is wrong, or your data is wrong, or something in your `ContentProvider` implementation is wrong.